# User fixing a single (same) spelling mistake (and nothing else) in loads of posts

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just happened to be assigned a load of edits like this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9875319

Basically, this edit corrects the same spelling mistake (equiv**e**lent instead of equiv**a**lent) in loads of posts. While this certainly fixes a mistake, it certainly doesn't improve readability. But it might improve discoverability, since they are mostly in the title of question. So should I actually accept these edits or are they just too minor?

Comment: @hvd Thanks, didn't find that by searching for "spelling" or similar wordings :-)

Comment: dupe of a dupe? This is getting silly. :-)